# Personal Hotspot changes location in Settings app

Tags: iphone, ios

On my iPhone, the **Personal Hotspot** appears directly under Settings app:

[image]

However, sometimes it  goes missing and can be found within **Mobile Data**:

[image] [image]

The behaviour doesn't seem to depend on anything. Sometimes it's here, sometimes it's there. Is there any reason for that?

I am using an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.3.3.